# git pull without downloading or cloning

Tags: git, github

I am new to git.
I have my project on my PC. My team mate has uploaded the same project with some changes on to github.

Is it possible to pull the changes on my project folder from github without downloading or cloning the repository ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is possible, just commit your changes & do git pull.

Comment: So your local copy is not currently a git repository? If that is the case, I would strongly suggest that you do clone the repo from github, and work on that. You really want to be using version control going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Without having local git repository it's quite difficult and error prone.

You can use `archive` command to download the snapshot of the project:

```
git archive --remote=https://github.com/youfriend/hisproject.git refs/branches/master > hisproject.tar
```

However, this will only download snapshot and override all the changes in your current project folder. If you don't have git repository locally, there is no way how git could understand what are just the changes.

The other way is to get patches from your friend's commits and then apply manually on your folder:

```
 # shows the commits:
git log
# shows the patch:
git show 3486064893fdd187c94800f228b636f1248c05dc > commit.diff
# applies patch on your tree:
patch -p1 < commit.diff
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to your detailed question, but the headline rather asks for a simple

```
git merge
```

The command is useful if you have already fetched (explicitly or possibly when you pulled a different branch) and just want to “pull” the current branch without re-fetching.

This is notable as perhaps some people might not be aware of the usage of that command without an explicit parent (so the parent is the remote-tracking branch, analogous to `git pull`), so this might hopefully be helpful for people coming here from a search.

Comment: this is pure magic, I used this to avoid redownloading large files that I already have locally.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the remote to your local git repository.

But this will make the first `git pull` problematic. If you have been working in isolated git repositories there is no way git will find common commits to base merge on.

So the safe path is to clone the github repository your colleague created and then apply your changes on top of the agreed starting point for collaboration.